"invalid signature in function definition" error message when using julia v1.10.4
Since updating to julia version 1.10.4 I'm receiving random errors like this

ERROR: LoadError: ParseError:
Error @ /path/test.jl:58:1
a=[1,2,3,4]
Invalid signature in function definition
Stacktrace:
[1] top-level scope
@ ~/path/test.jl:58
in expression starting at /path/test.jl:58

when writing very easy code snippets like this: a=[1,2,3,4] or a=plot(x,y), this also happens when defining other variables/ inbuilt functions from packages like Plots.jl or QuadGK.jl but does not happen all the time, e.g. when using the same code in another .jl file, has anyone ever experienced this?

You need to provide a minimal working example otherwise it's difficult to help you...
